# Upper bound on the order of the centralizer of the affine subgroup of $Sym(\mathbb{Z_n})$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Suppose $Sym(\mathbb{Z_n})$ is the group of all permutations of $\mathbb{Z_n}$.
Let $AF(n)$ denote affine group (the group of all mappings, that send $ x \ to\ ax+b $ for some $a$ and $b$ from $\mathbb{Z_n}$), which is a subgroup of $Sym(\mathbb{Z_n})$ and $C(g)$ denote the centralizer of an element $g$ in $Sym(\mathbb{Z_n})$. Is there a non-trivial upper bound on $\vert \lbrace{ C(k): k\in AF(n), k\neq 1\rbrace}\vert$? You may consider $n$ to be prime if required but upper bounds for general $n$ are better.

Comment: This question is very unclear. $AF(a,b)$ looks more like an element of a group than a group. What is $n$? What is $p$?

Comment: The original version asked for an upper bound on $\{ |C(k)| : k \in {\rm AF}(n) \}$. The revised version is just asking for $|C_{S_n}({\rm AF}(n))|$, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @Derek Holt yes I asked for largest center for non identity element not the intersection.   Edited version is just asking for the whole group

Comment: Rededited to version I wanted to ask for

Comment: I don't think my answer is useful for your original (not incorrectly edited question), To answer your second comment on my answer: all "affine" transformations of $G$ of the form $a\beta(x)$ are a composition of a left-multiplication $ax$ and an automorphism $\beta(x)$, so a permutation $\sigma$ of $G$ commutes with all affine maps if and only if it commutes with all left-multiplications and all automorphisms. I can delete my answer later unless you want it to stay up.

Comment: @runway That's okay . I think it's better to point out the situation in the begining of the answer if possible. The answer is good enough and provides useful insights to approach so it can stay up. Just if you point it out with an edit so that anyone looking at the solution is not confused, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

The answer below was in response to an earlier incorrectly edited version of the question.

---

The affine group $\mathrm{Aff}(d,\mathbb{Z}_p)=(\mathbb{Z}_n^d,+)\rtimes \mathrm{GL}(d,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is special case of a [**holomorph**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorph_(mathematics))

$$ \mathrm{Hol}(G)=G\rtimes\mathrm{Aut}(G). $$

There is an action $\mathrm{Hol}(G)\to\mathrm{Perm}(G)$ which sends $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ to itself and $G$ to left-multiplications-by-$g$s, as per Cayley's theorem. Say we want to find the centralizer $C$ of $\mathrm{Hol}(G)$ within $\mathrm{Perm}(G)$.

Every element of $\mathrm{Hol}(G)$ looks like $a\beta(x)$ for some $a\in G$, $\beta\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$. Suppose $\sigma\in C$. Then

$$ \sigma(a\beta(x))=a\beta(\sigma(x)) $$

identically. This can be broken up into two types of centralizing:

$$ \sigma(ax)=a\sigma(x), \qquad \sigma(\beta(x))=\beta(\sigma(x)). $$

The first implies $\sigma(a)=a\sigma(0)$. Substituting into the second,

$$ \beta(x)\sigma(0)=\beta(x\sigma(0))=\beta(x)\beta(\sigma(0)), $$

which is equivalent to $\beta(\sigma(0))=\sigma(0)$ for all $\beta\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$.

Therefore, all $\sigma\in C$ are of the form $\sigma(x)=xg$ where $g\in AZ(G)$ is in the [absolute center](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Absolute_center).

(A similar exercise shows the normalizer of $\mathrm{Hol}(G)$ in $\mathrm{Perm}(G)$ is $R(G)$, the set of all right-multiplications $\sigma(x)=xg$ for all $g\in G$.)

In the case of $G=(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$, the group operation is addition rather than multiplication, and the automorphisms are of the form $\beta(x)=bx$ for $b\in\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$. Our centralizing elements $\sigma(x)=x+y$ satisfy $by=y$ for all $b\in\mathbb{Z}_n$. If $n=2^km$ with $m$ odd we may write $\mathbb{Z}_n=\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}\times\mathbb{Z}_m$ (as rings even) and $b$ corresponds to $(b_0,b_1)$ with $b_0\in\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}^{\times}$ and $b_1\in\mathbb{Z}_m^{\times}$ and $y=(u,v)$. Setting $b=(1,2)$ in $by=y$ indicates $v=0$ and setting $b=(1+2^{k-1},1)$ indicates $u$ is even. Within $\mathbb{Z}_n$ this means $y$ is a multiple of $2m$.

The additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ generated by $2m$ has $n/(2m)=2^{k-1}$ elements if $k\ge 1$ and only $1$ element if instead $k=0$, i.e. if $n$ is odd.

Comment: The answer is really helpful but apparently the editor edited the question to change the meaning of question. I have edited the question back to the form I wanted to ask. Can you enter the edited answer so that it fits the question?

Comment: Also can you elaborate why the  commuting equality of $\sigma$ and $\alpha \beta$ must breakup into two commuting equalities that you mentioned ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to attempt to prove this for the moment, but I conjecture that the largest centralizer in $S_n$ occurs when $n = 2^k$ for some $k$,  with $g \in {\rm AF}(n)$ equal to the permutation $x \mapsto (2^{k-1}+1)x \bmod n$.

Then $g$ is an involution with $n/2$ fixed points (the even integers) and $n/4$ transpositions. Its centralizer in $S_n$ has order $\frac{n}{2}!\,\frac{n}{4}!\,2^{n/4}$.